# Extjs 4, How to autoHide menu in the toolbar?

Tags: extjs, menu, extjs4, toolbar

When I click the button on the tool bar the menu opens up and stays open.

so I need to click off to hide drop down menu box. That's not what I expect.

anybody know how to auto hide toolbar menu?

Here is my code:

```
{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    itemId : 'mainMenu',
    items: [
    {
        text : 'Main Menu 1',
        menu : {
        xtype: 'menu',
        items : [
            {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Contacts',
            itemId : 'extjs'
            },{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Orders',
            itemId: 'extjs2'
            }
        ]
        }
    },{
        text : 'Main Menu 2',
        xtype : 'button',
        itemId : 'extjs3'
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the default Menu behavior. The menu stays around until it is deactivated by any off clicks. If you would like to change that behavior you can add a listener for the mouse leave event on the menu and hide the menu at that point. 
Here is the listener that you need:

```
listeners:{
    'mouseleave': function( menu, e, eOpts){
          console.log('bye bye ');
          menu.hide();
      }
 }
```